# session is not destroyed when logging out

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i want **session destroy** logout but they don't work properly.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function logout(){
            $this->session->ses_destroy();
            redirect('users/index');
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="javascript:;">My Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:;">My Groups</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'Users/logout' ?>">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

**RESULT**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::ses_destroy()
```

Comment: sess_destroy not ses_destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some spelling mistake in your controller.

```
$this->session->ses_destroy(); replace $this->session->sess_destroy();
```

read sentence properly
link is : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html
check this link.

Answer (score 1):

You have typo. According to [CodeIginiter-2 documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), the method for destroying the sessions is `sess_destroy`, not `ses_destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error exist sess_destroy

```
public function logout(){
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('users/index');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an spell miskate in you controller.
**$this->session->sess_destroy()**
 instead of
**$this->session->ses_destroy()**

Please check below example to avoid your confusion:

```
    class Home extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            //this condition checks the existence of session if user is not accessing  
            //login method as it can be accessed without user session
            if( !$this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $this->router->method != 'login' ) {
                redirect('login'); 
            }
        }
        function index()
        {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['email'] = $session_data['email'];
            $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('home_content_view', $data);
        }

        function logout()
        {
            $this->session->userdata = array();
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('home', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

First store username and password detail in your session like this

```
 $this->session->set_userdata($this->data);
```

And then for session destroy use this code,

```
    public function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url().''); 
    }
```